next-intl: The Link component renders a URL with DefaultLocale
When using Link from routing, when rendering a link to the URL of the default locale, defaultLocale gets into the href
<a hreflang="en" href="/en/tools"> but I expect href="/tools"
This does not interfere with user navigation. But it is a problem for SEO
Because when crawling a site, non-existent pages will end up in the Google index. Thus eating up the crawling budget. Also disrupting internal linking, eating up link weight.
"next-intl": "^3.21.0-canary.0"
middleware.ts
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)',
    '/',
  ],
};

export const middleware = (request: NextRequest): NextResponse => {
  const {
    nextUrl: {pathname},
  } = request;
  const defaultLocale = request.headers.get('x-your-custom-locale') || 'en';

  const handleI18nRouting = createMiddleware(routing, {
    alternateLinks: true,
    localeDetection: true,
  });
  const response = handleI18nRouting(request);

  response.headers.set('x-your-custom-locale', defaultLocale);
  response.headers.set('x-middleware', 'true');
  response.headers.set('x-pathname', pathname);

  return response;

routing.ts
const routing = defineRouting(config);

const {Link, redirect, usePathname, useRouter} = createNavigation(routing);

export {routing, Link, redirect, usePathname, useRouter};

request.ts
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';

import {routing} from './routing';

const requestConfig = getRequestConfig(async ({requestLocale}) => {
  const locale = (await requestLocale) ?? routing.defaultLocale;

  const Common = (await import(`../locale/${locale}/common.json`)).default;
  const HomePage = (await import(`../locale/${locale}/home-page.json`)).default;

  return {
    locale,
    messages: {
      Common,
      HomePage,
    },
  };
});

export default requestConfig;

Switcher
{LOCALES.map((locale) => (
            <li key={locale}>
              <Link href={pathname} locale={locale}>
                   {locale}
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}


Before next-intl I had a custom utility localizedPath that accepted pathname and locale = returning the correct URL.

import {DEFAULT_LOCALE, LOCALES, type Locale} from '@/config/locale';

import {clearPathnameFromLocale} from './clear-pathname-from-locale';

const isIncludeLocale = (path: string): boolean =>
  new RegExp(
    `^\\/(${LOCALES.filter((locale) => locale !== DEFAULT_LOCALE).join('|')})(/|$)`,
  ).test(path);

const isExternalPath = (path: string): boolean =>
  ['http', 'https', 'tel:', 'mailto:', 'data:'].some((prefix) =>
    path.includes(prefix),
  );

const localizedPath = (
  path: string,
  locale: Locale = DEFAULT_LOCALE,
  options?: {replaceLocaleIfDifferent?: boolean},
): string => {
  const {replaceLocaleIfDifferent} = options || {};

  if (
    isExternalPath(path) ||
    (!replaceLocaleIfDifferent &&
      (locale === DEFAULT_LOCALE || isIncludeLocale(path)))
  ) {
    return path;
  }

  if (replaceLocaleIfDifferent) {
    return locale === DEFAULT_LOCALE
      ? clearPathnameFromLocale(path)
      : `/${locale}${clearPathnameFromLocale(path)}`;
  }

  return `/${locale}${path.startsWith('/') ? path : `/${path}`}`;
};

export {localizedPath};

If you do not use the link component from the routing, but a regular link with the utility, then everything works as expected

ClientLink.js from navigation using function:

function getLocalePrefix(locale, localePrefix) {
  var _localePrefix$prefixe;
  return localePrefix.mode !== 'never' && ((_localePrefix$prefixe = localePrefix.prefixes) === null || _localePrefix$prefixe === void 0 ? void 0 : _localePrefix$prefixe[locale]) ||
  // We return a prefix even if `mode: 'never'`. It's up to the consumer
  // to decide to use it or not.
  '/' + locale;
}

branch missing if locale === defaultLocale
